# How often does Concourse check resource versions?

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

From the [Concourse docs](https://concourse.ci/pipeline-mechanics.html#scheduling-with-resources)

> A new version can be found in an external resource by the check component of a resource finding a new set of versions when it runs. A check is run periodically for every resource in your pipeline.

How often does Concourse check your resources? Is this frequency configurable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking through the [Concourse docs](https://concourse-ci.org/resources.html#resource-check-every) in the resources section:

> Default 1m. The interval on which to check for new versions of the resource.

This is configurable in the resource definition under the `check_every` parameter. See https://concourse-ci.org/resources.html#resource-check-every.